# standard (idiomatic) way of convert an object to string

Tags: dylan

I tried to print an object of this class:

```
define class <bill> (<object>)
    slot num :: <string>;
    slot ref :: <string>;
end class <bill>;
```

I can make a method like `say`

```
define method say (bill : <bill>) => ();
    format-out("num:%s\n", bill.num);
    format-out("ref:%s\n", bill.ref);
end method say;
```

but I want a method to convert the object to `<string>` that can be used like

```
format-out("%s\n", bill);

or

format-out("%s\n", as(<string>, bill));

or

format-out("%=\n", bill);
```

I tried

```
define method as(type == <string>, bill :: <bill>) 
  => (s :: <string>);
  let result :: <stretchy-vector> = make(<stretchy-vector>);
  add!(result, bill.num);
  add!(result, bill.ref);
  join(result, " ");
end method as;
```

but with:

```
format-out("\%s\n", as(<string>,bill));
```

I had this result

```
Object {<bill>} cannot be converted to class {<class>: <string>}
Object {<bill> 0x1ff8180} cannot be converted to class {class <string> 0x7f5d5c645c00}
Breaking into debugger.
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

An with this:

```
format-out("%s\n", bill);
```

that result:

```
{<bill> #x00000000025EF1B0}
```

What I'm doing wrong? 
What is the standard (idiomatic) way of printing an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to adding support for printing an object is by specializing [print-object](http://opendylan.org/documentation/library-reference/io/print.html#io%3aprint%3aprint-object). But if you want to be able to convert object representation to string, specializing as generic is the way to go, as you did. It works here, so maybe there's a bug somewhere:

```
module: bill

define class <bill> (<object>)
  constant slot num :: <string>, init-keyword: num:;
  constant slot ref :: <string>, init-keyword: ref:
end class <bill>;

define method as(type == <string>, bill :: <bill>) => (s :: <string>);
  join(vector(bill.num, bill.ref), " ");
end method as;

format-out("%=\n", as(<string>, make(<bill>, num: "1", ref: "a")));
```

Result:

```
$ bill 
"1 a"
```

Comment: Thanks! The bug was in module import/export